# Facebook login using firebaseui doesn't work errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

I've followed [the Authenticate using Facebook Login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) guide.
When I reached "Authenticate with Firebase" it says I should follow the [Facebook developer's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).
As soon as I added the `facebook_app_id` in the Androidmanifest, which is in **4. Edit Your Resources and Manifest**, step 4:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

I got an error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from AndroidManifest.xml:52:13-52
    is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:50:9-52:55 to override.
```

It seems strange to add the key anyway, because I use Firebase so that I have an automatic drop-in UI, I'm expecting Firebase to handle this for me. The firebase documentation also says "If you integrated Facebook Login using a LoginButton" why would I want this? The whole reason you implement the firebase UI is so that you don't have to add a button etc.

When I remove `facebook_app_id`, then I get below error:

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1234567890' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

This seems to be the problem. This is the method:

```
override suspend fun makeSignInIntent(): Intent {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        // Choose authentication providers
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
//                AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
        )
        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Please note that I excluded `AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()` and still get the error.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0"
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.13.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.13.0'
```

My strings.xml:

```
<!-- Facebook application ID and custom URL scheme (app ID prefixed by 'fb'). -->
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">MY_KEY</string>
<!-- Facebook Application ID, prefixed by 'fb'. Enables Chrome Custom tabs. -->
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbMY_KEY</string>
```

I've enabled Facebook login and added the necessary keys:

[image]

I also added the redirect URI and the Development Key Hash:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Also tried [this documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/auth/readme.md/), but is the same.

Comment: Did you try to use `<string name="facebook_app_id">1234567890000</string>` instead of `<string name="facebook_application_id">1234567890000</string>` in your `strings.xml`. The string resource key should match the meta data facebook reference...

Comment: I think you should check @Vall0n comment, because in `strings.xml` you have an entry with the name `facebook_application_id` and in manifest you use `@string/facebook_app_id`. Change `facebook_application_id` to `facebook_app_id` inside your `strings.xml`.

Comment: i think you need to try after turn on In Development switch in last screenshot.
feel required information on setting -> basic -> appid, packagename, classname, keyhash etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding

```
<string name="facebook_application_id">MY_KEY</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">MY_KEY</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbMY_KEY</string>
```

To the strings.xml file and I changed the meta-data to include a tools:replace:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    tools:replace="android:value"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Comment: i did like this, but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: this actually prevented my app from even compiling - The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "meta-data" is not bound.

Answer (score 0):

In your string.xml file declare resources follow:

`<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">YOUR_ID</string>`
`<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbYOUR_ID</string>`

In App build.gradle, add at least dependencie 8.2+ version :

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2+'`

Finally in your providers from Activity add:

`List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build());`

I hope to have help you